# Library can't read post input in Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm new in CI, I have an input post named email and password in accounts controller like this:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->library('auth');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[12]');

if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $remember = $this->input->post('remember');
    if($this->auth->login($email, $password, $remember)){
```

Meanwhile in my auth library i access the params like this:

```
    public function login($email, $password, $remember)
{
    $user = $this->CI->user_model->by_email($email);
    $user_id = $user['id'];

    if ($user) {
        if (password_verify($password, $user['password'])) { //login succeed}
```

But i'm getting an error it said **Message: Undefined index: password**. i test the input post and it work fine and i don't spell wrong or something. so what do i miss here? for more information i'm sending this using Ajax.

Comment: did you, at any point, prior to the first code block you shared, load the auth library? if so, it is possible codeigniter is "caching" the instance for the request, and thus only the first init is actually populating the params variable (potentially with NULL). that being said, I'm not exactly sure why you are not choosing to just use the function like `login($email, $password)` this is completely acceptable in OOP and Codeigniter.

Comment: @alex at first i using like that but it came to error and then i try this approach cause it's written in CI docs. I don't know if request can be cached. so how can i clear and disable this in develoment mode? thanks.

Comment: sorry "cache" wasn't the best word, the instance can be "stored". this only persists for 1 request however and you can't disable it. so are you loading this library prior to the first code block shown above?? also you should have *no problem* doing it the `login($email, $password)` way -  if I were you I'd ask a question regarding that. the constructor way really **shouldn't** be used like this, although it should be entirely possible to make it work.

Comment: @Alex now i'm using $this->auth->login($email,$password) since when i use just login($email, $password) it gives me Call to undefined function login() error. But stll the problem still persist.

Comment: this my auth function now  public function login($email, $password, $remember)
 {
  $user = $this->CI->user_model->by_email($email);
  $user_id = $user['id'];

  if ($user) {
   if (password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {. but still undefined index password.

Comment: i'm editing the question with my latest code.

Comment: undefined index for which? `$password` or `$user['password']`. if it is the former than var_dump each of your function variables $email, $password, $remember and post it here. if it is the latter then `print_r($user)` and post it here (or better, as edit to question).

Comment: @Alex now i look silly, i just remember that i've changed my 'password' into 'password_hash' in MySQL. you right it's not from POST but the $user['password'] thanks for your help. you can write your answer so i can choose your answer. thanks before.